# A task was cancelled when calling to httpclient for the first time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am calling rest service from xamarin.forms shared project using HttpClient. For the first call it throws "Task was cancelled" and when I call it second time and so on , it works fine.
If I install the app first time in the device and call the service, it throws the error but after that it doesn't repeats.

After installation to the device, I can debug, run multiple times but no issue, but when I uninstall and then debug/run or in new device then this issue comes and only one time.

Below is my code.

I tried to see if the task is cancelled  by some another task or another process and added tried to catch through TaskCanceledException but it not being catched.

```cs
public static class HttpManager<T, R>
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private static readonly string baseUrl = "http://webapi.testwesite.org/api/";

    private static void Initialize()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0); 
    }
    public static async Task<T> PostAsync(R input, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            Initialize();
            return await PostMessag(input, url);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
                throw new Exception("Unable to contact server. Please try again");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to contact server. Please try again");
        }
    }

    private static async Task<T> PostMessag(R input, string url)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, input);
        T retunVal = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
        return retunVal;
    }

  }
```

Below is the stack trace

```sh
 at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
 [0x001d4] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:541 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0009e] 
  in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:281 
  at TestApp.iOS.HttpManager`2[T,R].PostMessag (R input, System.String url) [0x0007c] in <a6b47dd5314e460faeb66d5af59e3f81>:0 
  at TestApp.iOS.HttpManager`2[T,R].PostAsync (R input, System.String url) [0x00050] in <a6b47dd5314e460faeb66d5af59e3f81>:0 
2019-08-17 09:34:12.789 TestApp.iOS[12806:43127157] Canceled
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #10
The thread 0xa has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: You can try to debug step by step to find the exception.

Comment: Did you find out anything regarding this? I'm having kind of the same Problem, just that the exception is thrown every time, not just the first call

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? I've started experiencing the same issue with the first call.

Comment: after updating the Forms to latest version, it stopped. Dont know what was the problem but same code, I havent changed a bit except updating the Xamarin.Forms to latest version fixed it.

Comment: @DharmendraKumar in which version is it fixed? on 44.0991640 version it is not fixed

Comment: I too facing this issue only in iOS for Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2578 version. Android has no problem. Any fix?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's a timeout issue. This can be fixed by increasing the timeout value.

Comment: If you look at the below in the above code    _client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);_ I have set timeout of 20 minute. I also tried for 1 hour timeout but getting same error. This error is coming on the first request only. If I am making second request, to the same method, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it seems that calling HttpClient too soon is problematic. I was trying to call web api right when application starts, but didn't work. So I called it in the first page in the overridden method OnAppearing and it is working.